# How to GET data from API and show it on PHP page?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I want to make a page on my website with some data from an API. The website is made with Wordpress.

I have tried with various codes/functions found on web but with no success.

The API requires me to login by user, pass or token (I prefer token).

I'm new to API and PHP and I don't even know where to start.

If anyone used it before, I want to take data from Exoclick API.

From the API Interface on Exoclick I can see that the request is made with curl, I never used it before and I prefer not to. Here is an example

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer tokenhere' 'https://api.exoclick.com/v2/statistics/publisher/country?'
```

From the API manual, I found this code for login, but placing it in a random page for test, it just crashes my website:

```
<?php

        // Include Request and Response classes

        $url = 'https://api.exoclick.com/v2/login';

        $params = array(
                'api_token'  => 'tokenhere'
            );

        // Create a new Request object
        $request = new Request($url, 'POST', $params);

        // Send the request
        $request->send();

        // Get the Response object
        $response = $request->getResponse();

        if($response->getStatusCode() == 200) {

            // Retrieve the session token details
            $token = $response->getBodyDecoded();

            print_r($token);
        }
        else {

            echo $response->getStatusCode() . PHP_EOL;
            echo $response->getReasonPhrase() . PHP_EOL;
            echo $response->getBody() . PHP_EOL;
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Crashes on which line? With what error?

Comment: No error in console, I get a message (I think from Wordpress) with: The site is experiencing technical difficulties.

Comment: Not console. PHP error, server error log, API error. You have to find where the script ends (eg. by commenting all lines of code and uncomment one by one from top).

Comment: At this line : $request = new Request($url, 'POST', $params);

Comment: Sorry, I really don't know Exoclick API. It has to return any error code from API, or write st. down into error log on server. Check both, somewhere you'll find the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not familiar with APIs and the associated libraries, in my opinion you should start with using cURL to get the hang of things.  Also, a good way to familiarize yourself with APIs is using Postman.  You can use it to generate certain API calls in different code bases as well.

In your case, you first need to get a bearer token so you can make a request for the data you want.  In my example I will show you two functions you can use to make a GET request to the /campaigns endpoint, using a token you get from making an initial POST request.

Ultimately, the solution to your issue depends on a lot factors such as the type of data you're trying to get and how you want to display it.  Will you be requesting data with the button click, on page load, etc...

I would also recommend familiarizing yourself with Ajax, and how to make Ajax requests with jQuery/JS and Wordpress, as this can help you not only with this API but others as well.  Also learn how to traverse the data that is sent back to you, whether with PHP objects or arrays.

It takes some practice, but start by piecing together small bits that work, such as the below where you can at least get the data and echo it to the page.

```
<?php

// A function that will make a GET request to the /campaigns endpoint

function get_data_from_api() {

// Run the function that will make a POST request and return the token

$exoclick_token = get_token_from_api();

$new_token = $exoclick_token->token;

$auth_array = array(
        "Authorization:",
        "Bearer",
        $new_token
);

$new_token = implode(" ", $auth_array);

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.exoclick.com/v2/campaigns",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
     $new_token,
     "Content-Type: application/json",
     "cache-control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$data = json_decode($response, true);

// do something with the data

print_r($data);

}


function get_token_from_api() {

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.exoclick.com/v2/login",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "{\n\"api_token\": \"[ADD YOUR TOKEN]\"\n}",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Accept: */*",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache",
    "Connection: keep-alive",
    "Content-Type: application/json",
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

// Decode the response from the API

    $decoded_response_object = json_decode($response);

    curl_close($curl);

// Return the decoded response so you can use it to make another request
    return $decoded_response_object;

}

// Run the initial function
get_data_from_api();

?>
```

Comment: I have the token. I don't know how to get data now, but once I get how to login and request. I will probably manage to get the desired data. I want my data to be requested at page load.
I have tried before AJAX with jQuery/JS coding for Steam API (In Tampermonkey for some small data), but haven't always managed to make it work.
I have tried your code on the page and it breaks at the first row. I also tried to place the functions in functions.php and call in my page between php tags, but still brakes. Probably I'm doing something wrong, or there is something wrong with my Wordpress?

Comment: I have tested this and it works, but did make one edit to turn the returned data to an array rather than an object.  The token that you have is an API token.  You still need a Bearer Token to make requests.  The API token simply tells Exoclick that you are a valid user asking for authorization.  Exoclick then returns a Bearer Token to you, which you can use to make a request.  Make sure you add your own API token in the area where I have shown [ADD YOUR TOKEN].

Comment: I created an account to test this, and if you use this with an empty account this is what would be returned in the end: 

`Array
(
    [result] => Array
        (
        )

    [request_metadata] => Array
        (
            [limit] => 50
            [offset] => 0
            [count] => 0
        )

)`

Comment: I already placed my API token where you had a sample one.
But now with the new code, it works and the results are similar to yours.
I finally managed to get the data and place it on my page.
One more question, if I need to get data from two separate links, do I make another function to get data but different variables?
Thank you very much for your time!